# Not able to send more than 44 characters in serial port using TCL

Tags: tcl

Im trying to send commands of length over 44 characters, for which I am getting some garbage at the serial port.
But if I send the commands with less than 44 characters, then I am able to see what I send in the serial port.

Any idea why this is happening? And any solution?

following is the code I do:

```
proc open_com {} {
   if {$::GSW_SERIAL_TYPE == "COM"} {
      if { [catch {set ::gComPort [open  \\\\.\\COM15 RDWR]}] } {
         LogMesg "Error: Failed to open serial connection $::gComPort"
         exit
      }
      fconfigure $::gComPort -mode $::gSerialPortSpeed,n,8,1 -blocking 1 -buffering none -translation binary -ttycontrol {BREAK 0} -handshake none
      fileevent $::gComPort readable [list rd_chid $::gComPort]
   }
}

proc rd_chid {chid} {
   if { [catch {gets $chid msg} err] } {
      if {[eof $chid]} {
         puts "ERROR:EOF RETURNING"
         close $chid
      }
      return
   }
   if { [string first "\[fal\]:" [string tolower $msg]] != -1 } {
      set ::gPromptRcved 1
   }
}
```

Comment: What sort of corruption are you seeing?

Comment: For Ex : this is the command, I am giving: SWITCH_CLI "GSW_REGISTER_SET nRegAddr=0x003 nData=0x0080" ....but if you see in the serial port I am not getting the command read correctly. it shows something like this : SWITCH_CLI "GSW_REGISTER_SET nRegAddr=0x003 nta=0x80"...As you can see the last parameter has jumbled or its lost,since the command is greater than 44 characters...if I give small commands, then I am not seeing any issue like above